# MySQL Categories List vs Sepperate Categories Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a blogging website which lets you assign a category to a blog. The original table that I had looked like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+---------+
| ID | CATEGORY | TITLE | ARTICLE |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
| 01 | cars     | Title | Article |
| 02 | cars     | Title | Article |
| 03 | sport    | Title | Article |
| 04 | music    | Title | Article |
| 05 | music    | Title | Article |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
```

So as you can see, the category is a written attribute. The subject came up of having a sepperate categories list which I created to look like:

```
+-------------------+
| CAT_ID | CATEGORY |
+--    --+----------+
| 01     | cars     |
| 02     | sport    |
| 03     | music    |
+--------+----------+
```

Which alters the original table to:

```
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+---------+-----------+
| ID | BELONGS_TO_BLOG_ID | CATEGORY | TITLE | ARTICLE | AUTHOR_ID |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+---------+-----------+
| 01 | 01                 | 01       | Title | Article | 01        |
| 02 | 01                 | 01       | Title | Article | 01        |
| 03 | 02                 | 02       | Title | Article | 02        |
| 04 | 02                 | 03       | Title | Article | 03        |
| 05 | 02                 | 03       | Title | Article | 03        |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+---------+-----------+
```

Now if I wanted to delete `cars` which is category `01`, rather than delete it (because obviosly 2 articles are in this category) I would probably change this to `unnassigned`.  So no problems here but if I was then to delete `music` (`03`) and change this to `unnassigned` I would end up with ID's `01 & 03` being unnassigned. So now when I run searhes for `unnassigned` articles, which should return 4, I am only going to see 2 or an error.

Wouldn't it be better to have the original table and when someone changes category `cars` they simply `UPDATE` the record?

Comment: Use a [foreign key constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with ON DELETE SET NULL for the CATEGORY column in your changed table.

Comment: unassigned in the sense , do you mean changed featured to 0 is unassigned

Comment: @VMai So when the category is deleted in `categories_table`, the `category` in the `blogs_table` is automatically changed to NULL where recoord would have == 03 for example?

Comment: @user3177012 Yes, if you delete the category music with id = 03, then those values would be set to NULL in your other table. But come to mind. You would better have a category_articles junction table, because an article could be tagged with more than one category.

Comment: Thanks @VMai! The way my site works is that each blog only has one category so this should be fine. Can you set it to a number rather than NULL, so for example if 01 is unnassigned by default, then you can change to that?

Comment: @user3177012 No you can't do set with MySQL: **SET DEFAULT: This action is recognized by the MySQL parser, but both InnoDB and NDB reject table definitions containing ON DELETE SET DEFAULT or ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT clauses.** And SET DEFAULT would be what you want. Personally I'm thinking NULL the right way to have no category assigned.

Comment: @user3177012 You could use a trigger to set the value to your special value. But then you can't use foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can validate it . If you need to follow the  database rules definitely you have to check parent-child relationship between 2 tables. There are 3 ways

**1. `FOREIGN KEY`** : This will prevent parent deletion , until child record is there

```
ALTER TABLE items
ADD FOREIGN KEY (category)
REFERENCES category(categoryTable)
```

**2. Validation from php script** :Some storage engine may not support point 1. In that case you can simply validate using php. Before deleting category just count if it has some product are not

```
$sql="select count(*) as cnt  from items where category=CATEGORY_TO_BE_DELETED";

if(mysql_query('cnt')>0) //means it has some items 
  //do not delete or throw some error
else
  //delete
```

**3 Logical deletion/soft delete:** 
Sometimes you need to delete category (suppose you have 1000 products under it and you can't delete it). Then you can have some `flags` like `is_deleted`. You can `on` or `off` that `flag` to **delete undelete** it

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of using PHP as I understand that better. Could you clarify what you mean by Validate? Do you mean, if a blog exists with that category, the category cannot be deleted, only changed?

Comment: Yes, thank you - That makes much more sense to me. So now I can have a default `01 | unnasigned` row and the user must change their blogs to that before deleting the category, or if the category name is simply being changed then they can do this without any problems as the ID number will still match up - Or do I have that wrong?